# How to deal with an internship certificate draft full of obvious spelling mistakes?

Tags: professionalism, internship, references, germany, certification

I left an internship of three months in a small IT company and have finally received a draft for the internship certificate to check back per email.

The person who wrote it works in the accounting department, so she isn't familiar with the technical stuff I did.  She is also the boss' wife.

While the content is really good and positive, I have several concerns.  She made quite a few spelling and grammar mistakes. The list of things I did wasn't entirely correct. She emphasized unimportant stuff while leaving the interesting things out.

I sent her mail, kindly pointing out the proposed content changes.  I attached a revised version of the document, where I silently corrected all the spelling mistakes as well.

She answered with a new draft where my changes to the list of actions were applied, but all the typos remain.

What should I do now? I feel it's impolite and could be interpreted in a bad way to point out mistakes to a superior person although I'm not working there any more. On the other side, I doubt that the certificate would have any positive value in this shape and can be more harmful than good, if send to future recruiters.

Comment: This question is related, but there we are talking about *few minor* mistakes. The great number of mistakes in my document draft are really obvious. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/should-i-point-out-spelling-mistakes-in-a-reference-letter

Comment: Why do you care? Is it customary where you are to require certificates to prove you worked somewhere? And all that effort for only 3 months? I wouldn't ever send a document like that to a recruiter, even if it was a literary masterpiece. Edit: I checked your profile, are you talking about an [Arbeitszeugnis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeitszeugnis)? If so, those have negligible value anyway from what I know of them.

Comment: @Lilienthal Not 100% sure how to translate it, other similar words would be "internship reference" or "letter of recommendation".

Comment: So it *is* an Arbeitszeugnis that you're asking about?

Comment: This is indeed a bad situation if you need a "re-revision". I would just politely ask again and point to the spelling mistakes like. It's very important to make 100% clear that it's nothing personal but that it's very important for you. If you didn't do it in your first mail, you can also attach why you can't do it by yourself, plus adding some more excuses. Thats what *I* would do.

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes, kind of "Arbeitszeugnis", but for a three-months internship and not for a real job.

Comment: @OttoV. I don't understand what you mean by "If you didn't do it in your first mail, you can also attach why you can't do it by yourself" - I corrected the mistakes in the proposal I sent her back as reply to the first draft. I just thought to better not talk about it in the email text so she probably did not notice...

Comment: @ByteCommander Sorry for the bad formulation. I mean if you did not tell her the reason, why you can't change the document yourself, then you can explain her this reason in the next mail, even if the reason is obvious.

Comment: @OttoV. What do you mean by "I can't change the document myself"? of course I can not write my reference myself. And I have sent her a corrected draft as proposal, but I did not specifically mention that I corrected spelling mistakes, I only explicitly pointed out the content changes I would have liked.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, this is just what i mean. You can't (re-)write it for yourself. This sounds obvious, but if you tell her, she will less likely understand the criticism as an insult. Although i think you really have to tell her that you still found some spelling mistakes. You can also better say *typing mistakes*. This way it sounds like they where done by accident.

Comment: @OttoV. I agree about the typing mistakes, but not sure about how polite saying that I can't write it myself sounds... Thanks for your comments anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Kilisi and Lilienthal have both pointed out it is not really that important, I can understand your concern and it is something I myself would fret about. However, I'd view it as an opportunity to practice what could potentially be an uncomfortable conversation.

There is no way around correcting these mistakes without pointing them out to the person who made them. This situation will come up in your professional life a lot. Deal with it.

Politely approach him/her and say something to the tone of:

> "Hey, I took the liberty to correct some spelling/grammar mistakes in
>   this document. I hope you don't mind printing/emailing/issuing it to
>   me again. SORRY that I did not point them out earlier and caused
>   double the work for you."

How you do this in detail is up to you, but you really should have the interpersonal skills to point out other people's mistakes, without humiliating or offending them.

Good luck.

Comment: "it is something I myself would fret about" - did you mean the opposite? If you would not fret about something it generally means you would not give it much import. Maybe that's what you meant by that.

Comment: I think @Underdetermined means exactly what they said. Even if it's technically not super important, both OP and Underdetermined are bothered by documents with numerous spelling errors. They understand why OP would fret about it, and are offering a way to kindly suggest to the reference that they correct the mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

The certificate is valid, I deal with people from all sorts of places the majority of whom don't have English as a first language. I'm less interested in the spelling and grammar of their previous employer than their accomplishments.

So, so long as it's a positive document and portrays you well, I wouldn't worry about it too much. Not enough to go back a second time for a rewrite anyway.

Comment: Maybe I should add that it's not in English but German, which is the native language of both of us. And some of the mistakes are *really* obvious and almost hurting...

Comment: Unsure why that would make a difference, most applications and references I see are not in English.... are Germans particularly pedantic on spelling and grammar?

Comment: As it's not such an international language as English (which means less non-native speakers) and we have quite many sometimes pretty complicated grammar rules etc, I personally would say yes, it is more important than in English.

Comment: @Kilisi they sort of are. In my experience so far it is when you apply for a Company, but once proven it becomes considerably less important. Germany company's I have seen value foreign education less than a, well nearly anny German education.

Comment: On the other hand, if I were handed a letter of reference with that many mistakes, it would make me wonder whether the candidate had good enough judgment to avoid working for companies staffed by such low-caliber people.

Comment: @Blrfl you may be right, I take all reference letters with a grain of salt anyway though.

Comment: @Blrfl: I must admit that I never, ever, enquired during a job interview whether the company's HR department was capable of handling the basics of their native language, so I might end up in the same situation one day. Not on my current company though :-)

Comment: @gnasher729:  It is kind of a crapshoot, that's for sure.  Fortunately, my references are colleagues who don't speak on their employers' behalf.  :-)